# Error when transforming astropy table to pandas DataFrame to hdf file

Tags: pandas, hdf5, astropy

I'm trying to get some data from the Gaia catalog and then I transform the astropy table into a pandas DataFrame then I want to store it in an hdf5 file. I can't directly store the astropy table (result of the query) into an hdf5 file because I need to do some processing on it.

The problem is when I want to store the DataFrame into the hdf file I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrateur.UTILISA-D5U7HV7/Documents/MEGA/ipsa/cours/aero4/stage/working_directory/python/tests/stackoverflow_issue/1_panda_to_hdf/tohdf.py", line 8, in <module>
    pd_table.to_hdf("test.h5", key="test", format='table', data_columns=True, mode="w", encoding="utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur.UTILISA-D5U7HV7\Documents\MEGA\ipsa\cours\aero4\stage\working_directory\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2505, in to_hdf
    encoding=encoding,
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur.UTILISA-D5U7HV7\Documents\MEGA\ipsa\cours\aero4\stage\working_directory\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 282, in to_hdf
    f(store)
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur.UTILISA-D5U7HV7\Documents\MEGA\ipsa\cours\aero4\stage\working_directory\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 274, in <lambda>
    encoding=encoding,
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur.UTILISA-D5U7HV7\Documents\MEGA\ipsa\cours\aero4\stage\working_directory\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1042, in put
    errors=errors,
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur.UTILISA-D5U7HV7\Documents\MEGA\ipsa\cours\aero4\stage\working_directory\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1709, in _write_to_group
    data_columns=data_columns,
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur.UTILISA-D5U7HV7\Documents\MEGA\ipsa\cours\aero4\stage\working_directory\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 4143, in write
    data_columns=data_columns,
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur.UTILISA-D5U7HV7\Documents\MEGA\ipsa\cours\aero4\stage\working_directory\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3813, in _create_axes
    errors=self.errors,
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur.UTILISA-D5U7HV7\Documents\MEGA\ipsa\cours\aero4\stage\working_directory\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 4800, in _maybe_convert_for_string_atom
    for i in range(len(block.shape[0])):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I first thought that it was my computation that created a problem but even without it, I get the error.

Here is my code :

- First you need to get the file with the result of the query by running: (The query can take few minutes)

```
from astroquery.gaia import Gaia

job3 = Gaia.launch_job_async("SELECT * \
FROM gaiadr1.gaia_source \
WHERE CONTAINS(POINT('ICRS',gaiadr1.gaia_source.ra,gaiadr1.gaia_source.dec),CIRCLE('ICRS',56.75,24.1167,2))=1 \
AND abs(pmra_error/pmra)<0.10 \
AND abs(pmdec_error/pmdec)<0.10 \
AND pmra IS NOT NULL AND abs(pmra)>0 \
AND pmdec IS NOT NULL AND abs(pmdec)>0 \
AND pmra BETWEEN 15 AND 25 \
AND pmdec BETWEEN -55 AND -40;", dump_to_file=True)
print(job3)
p = job3.get_results()
```

- Then you can run the following code and it displays the error above. Just be careful with the name of the file in the `Table.read()` function because the query won't give the same name as in the example below.

```
from astropy.table import Table
import pandas as pd

table = Table.read("async_20200611171019.vot", format='votable')

pd_table = table.to_pandas()
print(pd_table)
pd_table.to_hdf("test.h5", key="test", format='table', data_columns=True, mode="w", encoding="utf-8")

hdf_table = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_hdf("test.h5"))
print(hdf_table)
```

Does anyone have an idea where this problem might come ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `phot_variable_flag` column has object dtype, i.e. it is a numpy array of objects.  It is also masked:

```
In [30]: table['phot_variable_flag'].dtype                                                                                                                    
Out[30]: dtype('O')

In [31]: type(table['phot_variable_flag'])                                                                                                                    
Out[31]: astropy.table.column.MaskedColumn
```

When I deleted that column then it was successfully written by pandas as HDF5.